# Помогите решить данную задачу

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-development

Бригада строителей выравнивают участок земли для постройки дома, разделенный на квадраты. Вам даётся массив ground, где ground[i] - высота квадрата i в метрах.

За одну операцию бригадиры опускают или поднимают квадрат i на один метр. Определите минимальное количество операций для полного выравнивания всего участка земли.

Ввод:

ground - целочисленный массив, 0<length(ground)<20, 0<ground[i]<200

Вывод:

Integer - количество операций, чтобы полностью выровнять участок, то есть сделать весь массив состоящим из одинаковых значений

Comment: А что вы уже сделали? Среднюю высоту нашли?

Comment: Честно, я вообще не понял эту задачу, но есть пример ground = [1, 3, 2, 2]
getResult(ground) = 2

За две операции можно сделать массив, состоящий из одинаковых значений.
[1, 3, 2, 2]
[*2*, 3, 2, 2]
[2, *2*, 2, 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша задача - найти такое конечное значение (высоту ровной площадки), чтобы сумма абсолютных отклонений от начальных значений до конечного была минимальной.

Такой минимум обеспечивается выбором **медианы** исходного массива. Посчитав медиану, находите `sum(abs(median-a[i]))` как ответ.

Comment: Подскажите, как научиться развязывать подобные задачки(книги, курсы и тд.) Синтаксис языка выучил, уже могу написать свое приложение, но задачи развязывать не умею. Учусь на первом курсе

Comment: В данном конкретном случае нагуглить непросто, нужна общая математическая эрудиция, а вообще есть же книжки по алгоритмам и олимпиадные задачам, сайты соответствующие, где можно от лёгкого прокачиваться, смотреть обсуждения задач, если никак не выходит.  Темы по книгам на сайте есть, поиском поищите